# How to calculate the sum of values generated by a loop

Tags: java, loops, math

I am an extreme beginner at this, so the answer might be obvious and staring me in the face. I need to add together three numbers generated by a loop. The numbers are random (btw 1 and 6) and taken from another method. I can't seem to figure out how to use any of the values generated by the loop once it terminates.

It's for a homework assignment where we're supposed to simulate a dice-rolling game, and part of the assignment is to add together three dice rolls in order to display the score. I assume I'm supposed to add together the three rolls in order to get the score, but I 1) don't know where to add them together (inside of the loop? outside of it, and how do I in that case retrieve the values from the loop?), and 2) don't even know if just saying that score = roll+roll+roll is the right way to go about it. I feel like have missed something somewhere.

```
int score = getScore();
  System.out.println(score);
} 
static int diceRoll () {
  int range = (6-1) + 1;
  double roll = Math.random() * range;
  return (int)roll + 1;
}
public static int getScore () {
  int score = 0;
  int roll = 0;
  int i = 1;
  for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    roll = diceRoll();
    //I added this in order to make sure that the first part works
    System.out.print(roll + " ");
  }
  score = roll+roll+roll;
  return score;
```

In an ideal world this would display three random numbers between (and including) 1 and 6 (which it does), as well as the sum of these three numbers (e.g for 2, 4, 6, score would be 12). 
It checks out sometimes, but most of the time it returns completely random numbers. I suspect that this is the completely wrong way of doing it, but I can't really think of what to do.

Comment: You gotta add the score increment inside the loop, 'score+=roll'. How did you expect that 'roll+roll+roll' would get you the correct sum? You use a single variable that's overwritten at every loop. You also don't need to initialize it.

Comment: I think the main problem is that I haven't really mastered loops, so I don't know how to play with the variables to get the result I want. In my mind I would have wanted the iterations to generate some nice variables called roll1, roll2 etc., but I figured that probably wouldn't work very well. 
Do I not need to initialise score in order for it to exist outside of the loop?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Conceptually, you initialize the score, which you _are_ doing with `int score = 0;` then each time you roll, you add the value rolled to the current score `roll = diceRoll(); score = /*the current*/score + roll;` ... and there is an idiom `score += roll` where `+=` means "add the value on the right side to the variable on the left". Think of doing this with an actual die, paper, and pencil, and the concepts are the same: initialize the score (get a piece of blank paper), roll the die, add the roll value to the current score on the paper - _before_ rolling the die again.

Answer (score -1):

**Code with comments**

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    int score = getScore();
    System.out.println(score);
}

static int diceRoll() {
    int min = 1;
    int max = 6;
    return ((int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min);//it'll return values between 1 and 6
}

public static int getScore() {
    int score = 0;
    int roll = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        roll = diceRoll();//you first need save the returned value
        score = score + roll; //at this point you accumulate the returned values
        System.out.print(roll + " ");
    }
    return score;
}
```